# Why the mms url download is not accessible via normal browsers

Tags: android, url, connection, mms

I am new in Android development, I wrote an app that lists cell content (I am interest in mms), where I came cross with a "ct_l" field containing a url like this: http://nfh.tim.br/021000838383839374972 (fake number). I wonder why this address do not work with normal browsers, they say that server is not found. Does anybody know if the cell phone changes this address to another scheme before accessing the mms? I wanted to know if there is a way to get mms content using this url, I am already reading the documentation, it seems that the navigator must be a specific one... there are some autentication involved, but in this case, this server should throw an error page, but only says that the server doesn't exist.
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the MMS content's URL is only accessible using the MMS APN configured in your device.

You can do a Content Query to read the device's MMS APN and use those values to configure your MMS connection request so it goes through the proper APN.